# Can't do anything in this view angle unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: I cannot see things and move things]

I don't know just started unity and this happened

Device name DESKTOP-11E0REU
Processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz   1.38 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (7.73 GB usable)
Device ID   CB15BA47-45FF-4065-AA08-32A9D4CDB654
Product ID  00330-70000-00002-AAOEM
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display

Specs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in isometric/orthographic view.

Click the center of the gizmo in the top right of the scene view window (the cube with axis handles).

This will change the view from isometric to perspective, and vice versa.

[Scene view navigation reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SceneViewNavigation.html)